# Extracting a string between two variable points in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, search, substring

I have a column which should contain text relatively similar to this

```
Storage Location: E10-2
Die Area: 28.90
```

Really all I care about is the "E10-2" portion.

The code I am posting below is the best I have come up with and I am cringing just looking at it.

First off, I'm relying on the fact that the lines have not been reversed. Second, I'm relying on two spaces preceding and a carriage return following the location.  Finally this a horribly long and cumbersome select string.

I looked into using dynamic SQL but that seemed even more cumbersome given the size of the size of the "FROM" statement.

Am I wrong?  Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this? Possibly validating part of the "Storage Location:" line so I know I'm looking at the right line of the field?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(BINARY(8000),RB.BITS)), 
    CHARINDEX(' ',CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(BINARY(8000),RB.BITS)),CHARINDEX(' ',CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(BINARY(8000),RB.BITS)))+1),
    CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(BINARY(8000),RB.BITS)))-CHARINDEX(' ',CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(BINARY(8000),RB.BITS)) ,CHARINDEX(' ',CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(BINARY(8000),RB.BITS)))+1))
FROM  
    TLS.DBO.REQUIREMENT R
INNER JOIN 
    TLS.DBO.REQUIREMENT_BINARY RB ON R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = RB.WORKORDER_BASE_ID 
                                  AND R.WORKORDER_LOT_ID = RB.WORKORDER_LOT_ID 
                                  AND R.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID = RB.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID 
                                  AND R.WORKORDER_SUB_ID = RB.WORKORDER_SUB_ID 
                                  AND R.PIECE_NO = RB.PIECE_NO
WHERE 
    R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = 'FP-01405-0032' AND
    R.PART_ID LIKE 'PCH%'
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing all the possible legal formats of the string you're trying to parse... but pulling out everything after "Storage Location: " up to and not including a CR or LF or space character (i.e. whitespace) seems reasonable. I'm not sure what type RB.BITS starts out as... or why you're casting to BINARY (8000)... maybe you could explain that?

Comment: The field I am parsing is encoded as an image. Yes, I could use a much smaller value than 8000 and I most likely will once I am finished fine tuning this qwery, however many of our fields are much larger.  Some approaching 8000 characters.  I believe 8000 is the max and I just use it as boilerplate code.

Comment: You should probably just use varbinary(max) and cast that to varchar(max) in that case. It's a cleaner conversion with no chance of truncation.

Comment: I am running SQL-Server 2008, I'm not sure if that functionality was enabled in a later version, but I can't use the keyword max.

Comment: sql server 2008 supports `max` unless you using SQL-CE.

Comment: Interesting,  It did work. I thought I had tried that before.  Thanks!

Comment: varbinary(max) was added when varchar(max) -- which you're using -- was added. It is supported in SQL Server 2008 and up. If you're having issues, check the "compatibility level" of your database and ensure it's at least 100.

Answer (score 1):

I like using a CTE to reduce the number of CONVERTs and CHARINDEXes as a first step:

```
;WITH TextStr AS (
    SELECT 
        Substring(
            Charindex('Storage Location:', 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), RB.BITS) ) + 17), DATALENGTH(RB.BITS)) as WorkStr
    FROM TLS.DBO.REQUIREMENT R
    INNER JOIN TLS.DBO.REQUIREMENT_BINARY RB ON
        R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = RB.WORKORDER_BASE_ID AND
        R.WORKORDER_LOT_ID = RB.WORKORDER_LOT_ID AND
        R.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID = RB.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID AND
        R.WORKORDER_SUB_ID = RB.WORKORDER_SUB_ID AND
        R.PIECE_NO = RB.PIECE_NO
    WHERE 
        R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = 'FP-01405-0032' AND
        R.PART_ID LIKE 'PCH%'
    )
SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(WorkStr, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), WorkStr + CHAR(10))-1)))
FROM TextStr
```

Basically, I search for your line's label, skip past it, and return a string containing all text after that point. Then I find the next Newline in the resulting string, and split the text there, retaining everything before the newline.

Assumptions made:

- Char(10) is your NewLine indicator
- The last line may or may not have a NewLine
- The Image field could theoretically have more than 8K Bytes in it

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Here is fixed code for the query:

```
;WITH TextStr AS (
    SELECT 
        Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), RB.BITS)),
            Charindex('Storage Location:', 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), RB.BITS) ) + 17), DATALENGTH(RB.BITS)) as WorkStr
    FROM TLS.DBO.REQUIREMENT R
    INNER JOIN TLS.DBO.REQUIREMENT_BINARY RB ON
        R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = RB.WORKORDER_BASE_ID AND
        R.WORKORDER_LOT_ID = RB.WORKORDER_LOT_ID AND
        R.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID = RB.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID AND
        R.WORKORDER_SUB_ID = RB.WORKORDER_SUB_ID AND
        R.PIECE_NO = RB.PIECE_NO
    WHERE 
        R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = 'FP-01405-0032' AND
        R.PART_ID LIKE 'PCH%'
    )
SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(WorkStr, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), WorkStr + CHAR(10))-1)))
FROM TextStr
```

Comment: I didn't think you could do that with charindex.  I've also never seen a query done like this.  However I am still having issues with this.  when I try to run your query it complains because there are only two substring arguments. When I add the converted RB.bits into the first parameter I get a conversion error from varchar to int.

Comment: Hm. You are right. I messed up the code. I was trying to make the code even simpler, and I broke it.